# Kendo Grid, ASP.NET Web API and serverGrouping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, telerik, kendo-grid

Does anybody know how to implement the server side part of serverGrouping in ASP.NET MVC 4 - withouth using the MVC wrappers provided by Telerik?

I have got serverPaging, serverSorting and serverFiltering working, but do not have a clue as to how to structure and send the grouped data.

Here is the code i have working for sending paged, sorted and filtered data.

```
public class TicketGridController : ApiController
{
    private SupplierDataContext db = new SupplierDataContext();
    HttpRequest request = HttpContext.Current.Request;

    // GET api/Tickets
    public Response Get()
    {
        int skip = request["skip"] == null ? 0 : int.Parse(request["skip"]);
        int take = request["take"] == null ? 10 : int.Parse(request["take"]);
        string group = request["group"] == null ? "" : request["group"];
        string status = request["filter[filters][0][value]"] == null ? "" : request["filter[filters][0][value]"];
        string sort = request["sort[0][field]"] == null ? "" : request["sort[0][field]"];
        bool sortUp = request["sort[0][dir]"] == null ? true : (request["sort[0][dir]"] == "asc" ? true : false);

        var Tickets = db.Tickets.ToList();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(status)) {
            Tickets = Tickets.Where(t => t.Issues.Where(i => i.Status == 1).Count() > 0).ToList();
        }

        switch (sort) {
            case "TicketID":
                if (sortUp) Tickets = Tickets.OrderBy(t => t.TicketID).ToList();
                else Tickets = Tickets.OrderByDescending(t => t.TicketID).ToList();
                break;
            case "TicketName":
                if (sortUp) Tickets = Tickets.OrderBy(t => t.TicketName).ToList();
                else Tickets = Tickets.OrderByDescending(t => t.TicketName).ToList();
                break;
            case "Status":
                if (sortUp) Tickets = Tickets.OrderBy(t => t.Status).ToList();
                else Tickets = Tickets.OrderByDescending(t => t.Status).ToList();
                break;
            default:
                Tickets = Tickets.OrderByDescending(t => t.DateModified).ToList();
                break;
        }

        // --------------------------------- 
        // ADD GROUPING SOMEHOW!?
        // ---------------------------------

        List<TicketDisplayObject> ts = new List<TicketDisplayObject>();
        foreach (Ticket t in Tickets.Skip(skip).Take(take))
        {
            ts.Add(new TicketDisplayObject(t));
        }
        return new Response(ts.ToArray(), Tickets.Count());
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to implement the grouping bit?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See KendoGridbinderEx project which is available on [github](https://github.com/StefH/KendoGridBinderEx) or [nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/KendoGridBinderEx/)

Please let me know if this implements what you need.